# Check Production and Staging environment inside HTML file in a React App

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to integrate a 3rd party app inside my React App. I have to use different keys for production and staging but I am unable to figure out how to achieve that in React and Node applications I can do it by `process.env` but in `index.html` I am unable to figure out how can I achieve that.

Here is my pseudocode which I am trying to pull for my `index.html` file for my `React` project

```html
<script>
if(env === production){
  some_app.init('TOKEN_FOR_PRODUCTION');
}
else{
  some_app.init('TOKEN_FOR_STAGING_OR_DEV');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While I personally prefer to store all API keys on the server itself, this guide indicates that there are other ways to do it:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-hide-your-api-keys-from-public-in-reactjs/

Additionally, to define differences between prod and staging in the front end alone, I recommend defining plug in variables using webpack:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Comment: Actually the initialization is on index.html yes for other 3rd party apps I have used .env file and neutrino for doing that.